# React - Google SpreadSheet failing to import

Tags: reactjs, google-sheets, vite

Trying to `import { GoogleSpreadsheet } from 'google-spreadsheet'` in my React App but getting this nasty error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at loadProxy (gaxios.ts:66:5)
    at node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js (gaxios.ts:75:1)
    at __require (chunk-RSJERJUL.js?v=0db569af:3:50)
    at node_modules/gaxios/build/src/index.js (index.ts:15:1)
    at __require (chunk-RSJERJUL.js?v=0db569af:3:50)
    at node_modules/gcp-metadata/build/src/index.js (index.ts:8:1)
    at __require (chunk-RSJERJUL.js?v=0db569af:3:50)
    at node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js (googleauth.js:19:21)
    at __require (chunk-RSJERJUL.js?v=0db569af:3:50)
    at node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/index.js (index.js:17:22)
```

here below is a screenshot of my current app structure that I have started using Vite (which maybe is why this is not working?)

[image]

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "tinder-triage",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "google-spreadsheet": "^3.3.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.27",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.1.0",
    "vite": "^4.1.0"
  }
}
```

**vite.config.js**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

Comment: [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet) you are trying to use has [github repo](https://github.com/theoephraim/node-google-spreadsheet) and there is "about" section there which tells "Google Sheets API (v4) wrapper for `Node.js`". Browser support not mentioned anywhere.

Comment: What does that mean? I might be too new to understand, sorry